# Sitecore is setting same language cookie multiple times in response headers

Tags: multilingual, multisite, cookies

Our multi-site Sitecore instance (7.0.- rev-130424) is setting same language cookie multiple times like below in response headers:

```
Set-Cookie: SiteName#lang=de-DE; path=/; secure; HttpOnly 
Set-Cookie:  SiteName#lang=de-DE; path=/; secure; HttpOnly 
Set-Cookie:  SiteName#lang=de-DE; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
```

This is happening like 40-50 odd times in some pages, because of the exceeded header counts, load balancers are not processing those pages. Have any of you faced this issue before?

Comment: Have you checked all the subsequent 7.x release notes to see if this problem has been fixed ? Is it possible for you to upgrade to 8.2 update 7 ?

Comment: Could you check to `GET` parameters of the request? I suspect there are more than one ```sc_lang=de-DE```. If it's true, then it may be processed several times by the `SetLanguage` processor.

Comment: No option to upgrade. I have checked release notes i could not find it as a known issue.

Comment: I have checked the GET parameters and there are no duplicates of sc_lang @RomanKlimenko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this answer is late but just answering in case it might help someone else. I believe this is an ASP .NET bug more details can be found in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28441024/4950874). Putting below code in the `EndRequest` event fixed this for me:

```
try
{
    var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(guid.ToString(), string.Empty));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove(guid.ToString());
}
catch (HttpException)
{
    //This means the headers were already written,
    //in which case we need not do anything.
}
```